# How to set TERM environment variable for linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, xterm

I've got very odd problem when I set export TERM=xterm-256color in ~/.bash_profile. When I try to run nano or emacs I get the following errors.

nano:

```
.rror opening terminal: xterm-256color
```

emacs:

```
 is not defined.type xterm-256color
If that is not the actual type of terminal you have,
use the Bourne shell command `TERM=... export TERM' (C-shell:
`setenv TERM ...') to specify the correct type.  It may be necessary
to do `unset TERMINFO' (C-shell: `unsetenv TERMINFO') as well.
```

If I manually enter the following into the shell it works

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

I'm stumped.

Comment: by default you have c shell from error message it seems. your might be changing the shell to bash after logging into the terminal?

Comment: Show actual lines from your bash profile and actual error messages. Format all code and messages as code. See [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Use the edit button to fix your question.

Comment: Well, this environment variable should be set by a terminal emulator which knows precisely what kind(s) of terminal emulation it supports

Comment: Why are you trying to set `TERM` manually in the first place. That generally is *not* the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you have DOS line feeds in your `.bash_profile`.  Don't edit files on Windows, and/or use a proper tool to copy them to your Linux system.

> <sup>Better yet, get rid of Windows.</sup>

In more detail, you probably can't see it, but the erroneous line actually reads

```
export TERM=xterm-256color^M
```

where `^M` is a literal DOS carriage return.

Like @EtanReisner mentions in a comment, you should not be hard-coding this value in your login files, anyway.  Linux tries very hard to set it to a sane value *depending on* things like which terminal you are actually using and how you are connected.  At most, you might want to override a *particular* value which the login process often chooses but which is not to your liking.  Let's say you want to change to `xterm-256color` iff the value is `xterm`:

```
case $TERM in xterm) TERM=xterm-256color;; esac
```

This is not a programming question and yet an extremely common question on StackOverflow.  Please google before asking.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I was using the slickedit editor on Windows over sftp. Luckily slickedit supports all combinations of line feeds when saving a file so it was easily fixed. Many thanks.